# List files in directory but not subdirectories PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code that I am using to list all the files in a specific directory which I then return as JSON

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$vars = filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

$id = $vars['id'];

$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/resources/' . $id;

$list = array(); //main array

if(is_dir($dir)){
if($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){

        if($file == "." or $file == ".."){
            //...
        } else { //create object with two fields

            array_push($list, $file);
        }
    }
}


echo json_encode($list);
}
?>
```

However, as well as returning the files, it is also returning a subdirectory that is also in that folder. How do change the if statement to also check whether it is an actual file that has been retrieved?

Comment: not your problem, but for correct operation of `readdir` `!= false` should be `!== false`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684881/php-how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-without-listing-subdirectories

Comment: Use glob() and array_filter()... <?php

header ( 'Content-Type: application/json' );

$vars = filter_input_array ( INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/resources/' . $vars['id'];

$list = array ( );

if ( is_dir ( $dir ) )
{
 $list = array_filter ( glob ( $dir . '/*' ), 'is_file' );
}

echo json_encode ( $list );

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meet [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/is_dir)

```
if ($file == "." or $file == ".." or is_dir($file)) {
```